# Is there a way to get UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged for compiled bindings?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm working on a UWP application and I realized that the default `UpdateSourceTrigger` mode for the `TextBox` control, which is `LostFocus`, can't be changed when using a compiled binding.

This means that whenever I want the binding to update for a `TextBox`, I have to use all this repeated boilerplate:

```xml
<TextBox
    Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Title, Mode=TwoWay}"
    TextChanged="TextBox_OnTextChanged"/>
```

```cs
private void TextBox_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.Title = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
}
```

Now, this is not too bad, but having to remember to create the `TextChanged` handler every single time a `TextBox` is used is annoying and error prone.

This would work fine with a classic binding:

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

But of course, here there would be the additional overhead of usinc classic bindings (involving runtime reflections, etc.).

Is there a way to get the same behaviour of `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` as well? I'd be completely fine with, say, writing a custom attached property that sets things up, as long as I can do everything I need directly from XAML, with no code behind involved.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** *(in response to Nico Zhu - MSFT's answer)*

> For my testing, it works well.

It doesn't for me, at all, As I said multiple times already, using `UpdateSourceTrigger` with `x:Bind` is just **not possible**. It doesn't compile, the property is shown in red in the XAML editor, it just isn't there. I really don't know where are you trying that, if you say it's working for you. I'm currently targeting 17763 as minimum and I can 100% guarantee that that does *not* work.

> Compiled Binding is used with the {x:Bind} syntax as opposed to the {Binding} syntax of Classic Binding.

I'm well aware of the difference, I've already mentioned this multiple times, both in my original question here (with code snippets too) as well as in my comments.

> It still uses the notifying interfaces (like INotifyPropertyChanged) to watch for changes

As I said, I'm aware of this too. But again, as from this question, this isn't the problem here at all. The issue is *not* with updates from the viewmodel *to* the bound property, but *from* the bound property (TextBox.Text in this case) *to* the viewmodel.

> `{x:Bind}` is by default OneTime compared to {Binding} which is OneWay. so you need to declare bind Mode OneWay or TwoWay for {x:Bind}.

I'm sorry, but I have to say at this point I'm starting to wonder if you've actually read my initial question at all. I'm aware of this, and in fact you can see in *both* my original code snippets that I had already used the explicit `Mode=TwoWay` property in both my bindings.

And once again, this was *not* what the question was about, at all.

To reiterate: the issue here is that the `TextBox.Text` property defaults to the `LostFocus` trigger, and that the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property is *not* available for compiled bindings. So I'd like to know if there's a way to achieve the same, with a compiled binding, in XAML-only, without having to manually create a `TextChanged` handler every single time (and if not, if you plan to eventually add the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property to compiled bindings too).

*Side note: I didn't mean to sound disrespectful here, and I hope we've now solved the existing misunderstandings with my question.*

**UPDATE #2:** turns out the issue was causing by the ReSharper plugin, which was marking the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property as error in compiled bindings.
I've opened an issue for that here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-474438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.updatesourcetrigger) documentation.

The default UpdateSourceTrigger value is `Default`. And 
using default behavior from the dependency property that uses the binding. In Windows Runtime, this evaluates the same as a value with `PropertyChanged`. If you used `Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Title, Mode=TwoWay}"`, the *Title* will be changed when text changes. we have not need modify the viewmode in `TextChanged` even handler.

The premise is that we need implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` like the follow.

```
public class HostViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string nextButtonText;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public HostViewModel()
    {
        this.NextButtonText = "Next";
    }

    public string NextButtonText
    {
        get { return this.nextButtonText; }
        set
        {
            this.nextButtonText = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        // Raise the PropertyChanged event, passing the name of the property whose value has changed.
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

For more detail please refer [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) document.

**Update**

> `<TextBox Text="{x:Bind Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />` doesn't compile at all, as I said the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property isn't available at all when using a compiled binding.

For my testing, it works well. Compiled Binding is used with the `{x:Bind}` syntax as opposed to the `{Binding}` syntax of Classic Binding. It still uses the notifying interfaces (like `INotifyPropertyChanged`) to watch for changes but `{x:Bind}` is by default OneTime compared to `{Binding}` which is OneWay.  so you need to declare bind **Mode** `OneWay` or `TwoWay` for `{x:Bind}`.

**Xaml**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title, Mode=OneWay}" /> <!--declare bind mode-->
</StackPanel>
```

**Code behind**

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
private string _title;
public string Title
{
    get
    {
        return _title;
    }
    set
    {
        _title = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, but this doesn't actually answer my question. I'm aware that the default `UpdateSourceTrigger` value is `Default`, which acts like `PropertyChanged` 99% of the times. I'm saying that, specifically, the `Text` property of the `TextBox` control uses instead the `LostFocus` trigger by default, and that when using a compiled binding it isn't possible to change that mode directly from the binding expression in XAML (unlike with classic bindings, as shown in my question).
Is there any way to do this directly from XAML, without the need for a `TextChanged` handler?

Comment: @Sergio0694, Ok, I will check that.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it! 

Comment: @Sergio0694 so, your main question  is *But of course, here there would be the additional overhead of usinc classic bindings (involving runtime reflections, etc.).* right?

Comment: Yeah, my questions basically are: "Why isn't the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property available for compiled bindings too", and "Is there a way to do the same in XAML-only, with compiled bindings, without having to fall back to classic bindings in this case"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192210/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-sergio0694).

Comment: `<TextBox Text="{x:Bind Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />` Does this work in your side?

Comment: I've read that, and have updated my question too with answers to all the different parts of your last update here (as it'd have been to long to type here in a comment).

Comment: @Sergio0694 Not so sure whether we've fully understand this issue. But I have worked with my college Nico and the following code actually works on ourside: <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />  Can you run the following [sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/App19) first? If it does not work, do you mind to tell us your detailed OS version? For example, when I type winver I will get 17763.437

Comment: Hey @BarryWang-MSFT and Nico Zhu - thank you so much for your help!
I've tested your repro project and after some more investigation I finally figured out what was causing the issue (and I think the misunderstanding here as well), it was ReSharper that was marking the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property as error on my end. Disabling it fixed the issue.
I've already opened an issue on the ReSharper issue tracker (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-474438), hopefully they'll fix it soon enough!
Thank you guys for your help, have a nice day! 